# How to maintaining Values between two different applications

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

We have a legacy application that is made in .NET, recently we decoupled a component from Legacy and built that using the latest tech (React and .NET API), we have used `redirect()` to access the new product from Legacy and it is working fine without any issues.

When I move from Product A to Product B it is good, but when a user wants to come back to Product A, it completely refreshes/reloads the Product A page, now the user requirement is to maintain the selections that were made before moving to Product B. I have tried multiple sites and most of the places say that is impossible; I need some expert thoughts if there is any way of doing it.

**Few pointers:**

Product A is made in VB.NET and has a different domain name (Parent).

Product B is made in .NET API and has a different domain name (Child).

Both applications share the same servers but different app pools.

Both applications use the same database to fetch data.

Comment: If both already use the DB, then use the DB? Otherwise you need some IPC (inter-process communication) like named pipe, TCP channel, shared memory, ...

Comment: what do you mean by same DB? are you saying to create a table and dump those values and fetch when redirection happens?

Comment: How about trying Redis or other Distributed Cache ?

Comment: Store selection info (in cookies, for example) for Product A before leaving, then when user comes back apply the stored info?

Comment: Take a look at Redis PubSub, it can be called from both sides, easily to sync values between 2 different applications, or consider using distributed cache- Redis can be useful with this as well

Comment: @amitagarwal unfortunately Redis is not used in my org.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang this is where the problem exists, you never know till when the user be in the Product B, until then I have to retain cookie info, on top of this, we have too many users who accesses both products, so storing it will again have more problematic to handle

Comment: In my imagination, cookie is stored in Product A, so the logic of controlling the cookie and applying selections will mostly be owned by Product A. Therefore, Product B shouldn't need to know what user chose in Product A, vice versa. Both of them only need to do saving upon redirecting(or once in a while in background) and applying upon user entering.

Answer (score 0):

You could save selection into navigation URLs. When navigating, safe referrer and use this URL to go back.

Comment: I had same idea to handle, now the selections will vary from user to user, so I need something to handle dynamically and handle those attributes when we receive.

Comment: you can handle it dynamically, URL of the current page can be changed by javascript.